# zoom only the clicked part of image JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, imageview

I am trying to get the image zooming effect using `JQuery`.

I have only one image that is of higher resolution, When i click any part of that image, i want to get the zoomed view of that part.

For example, i have one computer monitor image.Now if i click the button of monitor on image, the button should get zoomed.

I tried using this
http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/ but it is zooming the whole element.

How can i do this? are there any `JQuery` plugins available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is more what you are looking for? http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

Answer (score 2):

**For example, i have one computer monitor image.Now if i click the button of monitor on image,
the   button should get zoomed.**

This type of functionality cannot be obtained/achieved by using `zoomooz` plugin.It zoom the entire element in the container.

There are many plugins as per ur requirement:

1)http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

2)http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/zoom/           `multiple jquery plugins are here`

3)http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom

Answer (score 1):

Try this [jqzoom](http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/)
But it zoom on hover

[jQuery zoom plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/zoom/)

Answer (score 0):

`zoom.js` is also a good option. Here is the [demo](http://lab.hakim.se/zoom-js/) of that plugin.

If you are intrested in here is the [source code](https://github.com/hakimel/zoom.js)